# Hamcrest Matcher for no duplicates in a List of Strings?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, hamcrest

I would like a simple hamcrest matcher for finding duplicates of an object in a `List<String>`. This is what I wrote

```
for (QuizEntity quiz : quizzes)
            for (QuestionEntity question : quiz.getQuestions())
                Assert.assertThat("There should be no duplicate questions", 1, Matchers.equalTo(Collections.frequency(questions, question.getQuestion())));
```

Unfortunately I got this output, which isn't descriptive enough. Any

```
java.lang.AssertionError: There should be no duplicate questions
Expected: <20>
     but: was <1>
```

Comment: Can't you compare the `Set<String> questionText`'s length to the original quiz length? This is what I am doing in lack of a dedicated matcher

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replaced

```
Assert.assertThat("There should be no duplicate questions", 1, Matchers.equalTo(Collections.frequency(questions, question.getQuestion())));
```

with

```
Assert.assertThat("Question '" + question.getQuestion() + "' should not be duplicated", 1, Matchers.equalTo(Collections.frequency(questions, question.getQuestion())));
```

Answer (score 3):

Another option is to use [`hasDistinctElements()`](http://ozimov.github.io/cirneco/it/ozimov/cirneco/hamcrest/java7/collect/IsIterableWithDistinctElements.html#hasDistinctElements--) matcher from [Cirneco library](https://github.com/ozimov/cirneco) (that at the end is an Hamcrest extension).

It can be used as follows:

```
Assert.assertThat("There should be no duplicate questions", questions, CirnecoMatchersJ7.hasDistinctElements());
```

while I suggest to do

```
import static CirnecoMatchersJ7.*;
```

to make it more human readable

```
assertThat("There should be no duplicate questions", questions, hasDistinctElements());
```

Cirneco also has some fluent representation, i.e.

```
given(questions).withReason("There should be no duplicate questions").assertThat(hasDistinctElements());
```

---

The dependency can be imported as follows:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>it.ozimov</groupId>
  <artifactId>java7-hamcrest-matchers</artifactId>
  <version>0.7.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 3):

There's actually an implemented method that does exactly this - [doesNotHaveDuplicates](http://joel-costigliola.github.io/assertj/core/api/org/assertj/core/api/AbstractLongArrayAssert.html#doesNotHaveDuplicates())

```
 Assertions.assertThat(list).doesNotHaveDuplicates();
```

you could take quizzes and map it using Java 8 to the questions and assert there are no duplicates

Comment: The most clean and elegant solution

Comment: This is an AssertJ function. The question was about Hamcrest.

Answer (score 2):

I implemented my own matcher for that. Please note the error message did not work correctly to me (displayed another entry than the duplicate one). I share the code with the community (please link and upvote if you want to use in your product)

### The code

```
public static class DistinctMatcher<T> extends BaseMatcher<T>
{
    private final Set<T> theSet = new HashSet<>();

    public static <T> Matcher<? super T> distinct()
    {
        return new DistinctMatcher<T>();
    }

    @Override
    public void describeTo(Description description)
    {
        description.appendText("has distinct values");
    }

    @Override
    public void describeMismatch(Object item, Description description)
    {
        description.appendText("element found twice: ").appendValue(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public boolean matches(Object arg0)
    {
        return theSet.add((T) arg0);
    }

}
```

### How it works

By maintaining a stateful `HashSet`, the matcher is instantiated once and fed by each item of the iteration. According to `Set.add` method, it tells you whether the set contains or not the item already, so matching is immediate.

### Usage: (I tested it on a not-nested collection)

```
assertThat(quizzes,(everyItem(hasProperty("questions",everyItem(hasProperty("question",is(distinct())))))));
```

### Performance considerations

The above matcher is not suitable for unconstrained lazy collections (e.g. iterator over billions of records) because the `Set` holds a permanent reference to the object. One could easily modify the matcher to own only the `hashCode` of the object, but should keep in mind memory requirements.

Any other set-based solution suffers the same issue